# Is "vanilla extract" the same as "pure vanilla extract"?

Tags: vanilla, extracts

My cookie recipe says to use 1 tsp of vanilla extract. I have "pure* vanilla extract. Do I still use 1 tsp of it or should I use less?

Comment: Isn't vanilla extract usually pure? I'm not familiar with diluted vanilla extract.

Comment: @Erik usually they say "pure" to separate it from "imitation". :)

Comment: Just as long as it isn't "premium" vanilla extract; boy, do I hate that word...

Answer (score 3):

Vanilla extract and pure vanilla extract mean the same thing. Artificially flavored vanilla extract is also used the same way, with the same measurements.